# kendo mvvm binding within a template

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

I am trying to kendo mvvm bind within a template.  Template variables are working but none of the MVVM stuff is.

```
<div id="list"></div>

<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div>
    <button data-bind="visible:  alreadyAttending, click: onClick">
        Your id is ${ID} 
    </button>
  </div>
</script>

var data = [];
data[0] = { alreadyAttending:  true, ID:  1, onClick:  function() { alert("Click 1"); }};
data[1] = { alreadyAttending:  false, ID:  2, onClick:  function() { alert("Click 2"); }};

 $("#list").kendoListView({
   dataSource: data,
   template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
 });
```

Fiddle available here:  https://jsfiddle.net/q99ufo3c/5/

You can see the buttons are replaced with values from the data array, but visibility and click events are not wired up.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Does anyone know if this is supported?

Comment: you're mixing mvvm with the jquery syntax. You need a model (kendo observable) and bind a container div to that model. you also need to specify the template in your list div

Answer (score 0):

You need to define some data attribute to the `div` element so that Kendo can bind it correctly to your View Model.

- `data-role="listview"` - defines a [listview](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listview/index) component;
- `data-template="yourtemplateid"` - defines the template to be used;
- [`data-bind="source: dataSource"`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/source) - defines what is the data
  source of the listview component;

In the Javascript you need to have a Model that represents your object that will be in the data source of the list view. I created one called `vm` and I have chosen to use the [`ObservableObject`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/how-to/extend-observable-object) extend method because it is useful when you want to create an object with default values, such as the `onClick` method.

Please, take a look at the Snippet below.

```js
(function() {
  var vm = kendo.data.ObservableObject.extend({
    init: function(values) {
      var defaultValues = {
        alreadyAttending: false,
        ID: null
      };
      kendo.data.ObservableObject.fn.init.call(this, $.extend({}, defaultValues, values));
    },
    onClick: function() {
      alert(this.get("ID"));
    }
  });

  var source = [
    new vm({
      alreadyAttending: true,
      ID: 1
    }),
    new vm({
      alreadyAttending: false,
      ID: 2
    })
  ];

  var mainViewModel = kendo.observable({
    dataSource: source
  });

  kendo.bind($("#list"), mainViewModel);
})();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="list" data-role="listview" data-template="template" data-bind="source: dataSource"></div>
  <script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div>
      <button data-bind="visible: alreadyAttending, click: onClick">
         Your id is #:ID#
       </button>
    </div>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```